# Install a .bpk into Borland C++ Builder from the command line

Tags: delphi, c++builder, delphi-5

I am attempting to install a .bpk package into the Borland C++ Builder 5 IDE from the command line.  I am sure that this is possible, as we have some third party components that manage to do so, but I have not been able to figure out the required steps.

Any pointers are appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The packages are installed by creating registry values in the following location:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Borland\C++Builder\5.0\Known Packages`

If you look there you will see all the VCL packages, as well as any 3rd-party packages you might have installed.

Use a command-line registry editing tool, or write your own, to create the necessary string values in that location.

Comment: Missed it by about three keystrokes. <g> You're quick, Jon.